# Docker container with own docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

For reserach purpose I am testing the cyberbattlesim environment by microsoft. The gitHub repository of the project is at https://github.com/microsoft/CyberBattleSim. I am using an windows machine with docker. I am trying to run the project with docker container. Although I am able to build the image with the Dockerfile, I am facing problem following their comments

"
publish the resulting image to your own docker registry and replace the registry name in the commands below.

```
`Running from Docker registry
commit=7c1f8c80bc53353937e3c69b0f5f799ebb2b03ee
docker login spinshot.azurecr.io
docker pull spinshot.azurecr.io/cyberbattle:$commit
docker run -it spinshot.azurecr.io/cyberbattle:$commit python -m cyberbattle.agents.baseline.run`
```

"

Kindly provide some suggestions, how I should proceed.

I have build the docker image but when I try to run the container it just stops.

Comment: your question is not clear? what is the error message? Your code shows snippet to run container but your are talking about pushing containers. How and where are you pushing your containers?

Comment: I have used the Dockerfile from the GitHub repository to build the image but when I use the code 
'docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/source --rm cyberbattle:1.1 python -m cyberbattle.agents.baseline.run'
The container fails to run and I cannot run the code 
'python cyberbattle/agents/baseline/run.py --training_episode_count 5 --eval_episode_count 3 --iteration_count 100 --rewardplot_width 80  --chain_size=4 --ownership_goal 0.2'
to test the RL environment. I am using an windows machine to run the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem in your code. Try to jump into the container first and then execute your code on the CLI to see the exact error.

1. Run your container, but instead of executing your code, run the shell first.

```bash
docker run -it spinshot.azurecr.io/cyberbattle:$commit bash
```

2. Once you are in the container (shell), execute your code and see the error message.

```bash
root@7a1f557c8964:/>python -m cyberbattle.agents.baseline.run
```

3. Fix the issue and repeat.